# Mac system is not detecting Micromax A57 on eclipse to debug the app

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I searched about this problem, no one is not answered about this problem with Mac system, In Mac System, Micromax A57 device is not detecting when try to run the app directly from eclipse.
Eclipse listed Samsung and HTC desire C devices but it is not listing Micromax A57.

In Manifest File, on application tag assigned debuggable = "true"

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
     .......
     .......

   </application>
```

and in micromax device enabled USB debugging option.
but in eclipse on mac system is not listed only Micromax A57 device. Please any one can help to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi @Renga have you tried to connect the device with the other unplugged?

Comment: Hi @ Dyna, Yes i have connected device with Mac using HTC plug

Comment: I faced this on Ubuntu, but later I resolved it by defining a rules-51 file. I had to query the OEM from console and in my two micromax devices, one showed OEM as Google the other as HTC. These are cheap quality low end phones.

Comment: However I would like to add that my other device (Micromax A110 Canavas HD) was detected by my Mac mini at the first go itself.I could run the apps directly on the device without further intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally worked with Micromax Devices but problem seems to be common, I assume you have enabled the debugging on your device? Try to install  **Moborobo**  management tool for android, after installing try to stop and start ADT tool again, I hope it works.

[Here is one similar problem with some workaround](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41076/micromax-a57-is-not-displayed-in-eclipse-device-list/44130#44130)

Comment: I saw the same problem it is for Windows machine.